# Boost spirit parser attribute type not working.

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

```
int main() {
    std::string input("A90 (a-><>b)");
    std::string::iterator strbegin = input.begin();
    map<char, int> p;
    qi::phrase_parse(strbegin, input.end(),
    (qi::char_ >> qi::int_) % ':', // parser grammar
    qi::space, // delimiter grammar
    p); // attribute to fill while parsing
    return 0;
}
```

This code gives me error -

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::pair<char, int>::pair(const char&)’
```

and I am clueless on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need include `"boost/fusion/include/std_pair.hpp"`